# javafx gridpane layout with wrapping text

Tags: java, javafx

I am working in JavaFX 8.  Trying to use the GridPage to display a set of attributes and values.  Some of the values may be long enough to not fit on one line.  I would like to wrap those values, but can't seem to figure out how to get the grid pane to expand vertically to accommodate the wrapped text.  I Basically want behavior like you'd see in an HTML table.  Not sure if there is a different layout in JavaFX I should be using.

```
Property A    Value A
Property B    Value B
Property C    The Values for property C is so long
              that it wraps
Property D    Value D
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you have things set up?

Comment: This should be easily attainable by setting VGrow and using `TextFlow`. as James_D said it would be helpful if you showed what you currently have / what you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructed using [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/):

[image: small]
[image: large]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox prefWidth="220.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane hgap="20.0" vgap="10.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="20.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" valignment="TOP" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" valignment="TOP" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" valignment="TOP" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Property A" />
            <Label text="Property B" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Property C" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Value A" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Label text="The value for property B is so long that it wraps" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Value C" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the working example, that was enough.  I had been using the prefHeight attribute on the row constraints to give the proper spacing, which was causing the text to not wrap.  Seems so obvious now.